# Desynchronizing GIFs

Tags: javascript, html, image, background-image, gif

I don't know how to **desynchronize** these two GIF images.

I tested them in the following browsers: Opera and Edge.

When I start the first GIF (on the left), I expect the second one to begin its animation independently. However, they are not desynchronizing as expected.

The second one starts in the **middle** of its animation, precisely at the **same moment** the first one is at.

- How it is possible that `#gif2` doesn't start it's own gif-animation?
- They are both using the same gif, from the same "stream"?

```js
function show1() {
  let gif1Element = document.getElementById("gif1")
  setTimeout(
    () => {
      gif1Element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://i.imgur.com/pgFWygm.gif")'
    }, 0
  )
}
show1()

function show2() {
  let gif2Element = document.getElementById("gif2")
  setTimeout(
    () => {
      gif2Element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://i.imgur.com/pgFWygm.gif")'
    }, 400
  )
}
show2()
```

```css
#gif1,
#gif2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#gif2 {
  left: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div id="gif1"></div>
<div id="gif2"></div>
```

- I was trying to use `<img>` tag, but result was exactly the same.
- I heard that I need to reset source of an element.

But I think that shouldn't be looking like this:

```
function restartGif(img) {
  let src = img.src;
  img.src = '';
  img.src = src;
}
```

*I just want to add that I apologize for my English. I'm still learning*

Comment: Probably because they are using the same background image? This way the browser only needs to load a single image (think of a spritesheet of video game 2D sprite images) to save on bandwidth.

Comment: In other words, try to use two different image files. They can have the same content, but the files must be different.

Comment: it's a matter of browser memory management: You just have 2 display of the same image. there is no sync or de-sync problem.

Comment: simplest fix, append `?_=1` and `?_=2` to the URL's

Comment: though, you may want to add some randomness to those numbers too

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks, now it works perfect. But it's a pity that I have to use different files for every single explosion.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I don't quite understand what you mean by those spritesheets? Do you have any article about? I could read it then.
Btw thanks for editing 

Comment: You can use the same file, and still make the browser think they are different files, by using parameters. Something like: `https://i.imgur.com/pgFWygm.gif?ExplosionNo=1` and `https://i.imgur.com/pgFWygm.gif?ExplosionNo=2`. Because the argument has a different value the browser will treat them as different files. The only gain here is that you don't need to store multiple images on your server.

Answer (score 1):

(*For those, who don't read the comment section*) just add a `?ExplosionNo=1` and a `?ExplosionNo=2` to the gifs, like so:

```js
function show1() {
  let gif1Element = document.getElementById("gif1")
  setTimeout(
    () => {
      gif1Element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://i.imgur.com/pgFWygm.gif?ExplosionNo=1")'
    }, 0
  )
}
show1()

function show2() {
  let gif2Element = document.getElementById("gif2")
  setTimeout(
    () => {
      gif2Element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://i.imgur.com/pgFWygm.gif?ExplosionNo=2")'
    }, 400
  )
}
show2()
```

```css
#gif1,
#gif2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#gif2 {
  left: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div id="gif1"></div>
<div id="gif2"></div>
```